# How to run my switch statment after each function has ran?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make it so when i run a function, it also runs my switch statement as well, so that my "choice" variable is checked (via switch) to decide what to output to the user.

When function1() runs... Run switch... case "option1"... Javascript tel me that "Option 1 is selected".

Could i just wrap my switch statement in a for loop and have an argument look for when either of my three functions runs, it runs the switch statement?

```
    var choice = "undefined"; 

    function option1 () {
      "use strict";
      var choice = "option1";
    }
    function option2 () {
      "use strict";
      var choice = "option2";
    }
    function option3 () {
      "use strict";
      var choice = "option3";
    }

    switch (choice) {
      case 'option1':
        alert("Option 1 selected");    
        break;
      case 'option2':
        alert("Option 2 selected");    
        break;
      case 'option3':
        alert("Option 3 selected");    
        break;
      default:

      break;
    }
```

Comment: Observing values is very complicated, you'd have to use a proxy. I can only recommend to design your problem differently.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also suggest working through some JavaScript tutorials and/or a beginning JavaScript book before starting posting JS questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why not just put `alert("Option 1 selected");` inside your function `option1`, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to re-run your switch statement when the variable changes. Also the `choice` variables in your `option` functions shouldn't be re-declared with `var` (you're creating a new variable rather than assigning to the existing variable).

```js
var choice = "undefined"; 

function option1 () {
  "use strict";
  choice = "option1";
  onChoiceChange();
}

function option2 () {
  "use strict";
  choice = "option2";
  onChoiceChange();
}

function option3 () {
  "use strict";
  choice = "option3";
  onChoiceChange();
}

function onChoiceChange() {
  switch (choice) {
    case 'option1':
      alert("Option 1 selected");    
      break;
    case 'option2':
      alert("Option 2 selected");    
      break;
    case 'option3':
      alert("Option 3 selected");    
      break;
    default:

    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! This makes completely more sense! I'll give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do...

```
<a class="button" href="#" onClick="choice('option1')">Choice Me</a>

function choice(valor) {

  switch (valor) {
      case 'option1':
        alert("Option 1 selected");    
        break;
      case 'option2':
        alert("Option 2 selected");    
        break;
      case 'option3':
        alert("Option 3 selected");    
        break;
      default:

      break;
    }
}
```